# Selecting an option in AgularJS only when there is one item in the model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model

I'm very new to AngularJS and I'm having trouble implementing the logic for this dropdown - I want to select the first member in the model only if there is one member in the model. I don't know if having a default option that is selected in other circumstances is complicating the issue.

```
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:1rem">
        <label class="form-label">Member name</label>
        <small>
            <i>
                These are the members who have cover on the <u>date selected</u> above.
            </i>
        </small>
        <div class="input-group mt-1">
            <select ng-model="model.treatment.member" ng-change="ctrl.loadBenefits()" class="select" id="claimMemberName" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">{{model.members.length ? 'Select member' : 'Enter date of visit first'}}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="m in model.members" value="{{m.memberId}}">{{m.memberName}}</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is the best way to do this an ng-init on the Select or a function called in the option that populates the model into the view?

I'm used to Razor for manipulating models and honestly any help would be a lifesaver, it's never fun being stumped by something that seems simple on the face of it!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the place to do this is after you load/set your members list. You can add an if statement which would check the length and set model accordingly.

```
if($scope.model.members.length == 1){
    $scope.model.treatment.member = $scope.model.members[0].memberId;
}
```